# in query in Ember JS DS.store model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have tried below both queries :

```
    this.store.query('estimate', { 'vendorUids' : supplierData.getEach('vendorUid') } ).then((estimatesData)=>{

});

this.store.query('estimate', { filter : { 'vendorUids' : supplierData.getEach('vendorUid') } }).then((estimatesData)=>{

});
```

But it is creating queries as below :

```
https://localhost:8080/v1/estimates?vendorUids[]=344&vendorUids[]=5&vendorUids[]=1&vendorUids[]=2&vendorUids[]=3&vendorUids[]=4

https://localhost:8080/v1/estimates?filter[vendorUid][]=344&filter[vendorUid][]=344&filter[vendorUid][]=344
```

I want query to be generated as below like in query :

```
https://localhost:8080/v1/estimates?vendorUids=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In your second attempy you can try `supplierData.mapBy('vendorUid')`

Comment: This is not working. Still api request is like https://localhost:8080/v1/estimates?vendorUids[]=1&vendorUids[]=2

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me :

```
supplierData.getEach('vendorUid').toString();
```